# Print via ad-hoc network to wireless printer?

Tags: ad-hoc-networks, printing

Is there a way to print from an android device to a wireless printer connected to the ad-hoc network being broadcast by the android device?

Comment: Android devices don't support ad hoc networks very commonly, are you referring to the personal hotspot feature? AFAIK it creates an infrastructure network, not an ad hoc one.

Comment: Yeah, the personal hotspot mode. The printer successfully connects to the hotspot however when I try to add the printer via PrinterShare from there it doesn't find it. It seems like all the devices on the network are isolated from one another and the printer clients can't locally access the phone and vis-a-versa.